# Rotation of 3D vector?

Tags: python, vector, rotation

I have two vectors as Python lists and an angle. E.g.:

```
v = [3, 5, 0]
axis = [4, 4, 1]
theta = 1.2  # In radians.
```

What is the best/easiest way to get the resulting vector when rotating the `v` vector around the `axis`?

The rotation should appear to be counter clockwise for an observer to whom the `axis` vector is pointing. This is called the [right hand rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_hand_rule)

Comment: I find it very surprising that there is no functionality for this in SciPy (or similar easily accessible package); vector rotation isn't that exotic.

Comment: Now there is: [scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_rotvec](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_rotvec.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_rotvec)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at http://vpython.org/contents/docs/visual/VisualIntro.html.

It provides a `vector` class which has a method `A.rotate(theta,B)`. It also provides a helper function `rotate(A,theta,B)` if you don't want to call the method on `A`.

http://vpython.org/contents/docs/visual/vector.html

Answer (score 134):

Using the [Euler-Rodrigues formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Rodrigues_parameters):

```
import numpy as np
import math

def rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
    """
    Return the rotation matrix associated with counterclockwise rotation about
    the given axis by theta radians.
    """
    axis = np.asarray(axis)
    axis = axis / math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    a = math.cos(theta / 2.0)
    b, c, d = -axis * math.sin(theta / 2.0)
    aa, bb, cc, dd = a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b * c, a * d, a * c, a * b, b * d, c * d
    return np.array([[aa + bb - cc - dd, 2 * (bc + ad), 2 * (bd - ac)],
                     [2 * (bc - ad), aa + cc - bb - dd, 2 * (cd + ab)],
                     [2 * (bd + ac), 2 * (cd - ab), aa + dd - bb - cc]])

v = [3, 5, 0]
axis = [4, 4, 1]
theta = 1.2 

print(np.dot(rotation_matrix(axis, theta), v)) 
# [ 2.74911638  4.77180932  1.91629719]
```

Comment: @bougui: Using `np.linalg.norm` instead of `np.sqrt(np.dot(...))` seemed like a nice improvement to me, but `timeit` tests showed `np.sqrt(np.dot(...))` was 2.5x faster than `np.linalg.norm`, at least on my machine, so I'm sticking with `np.sqrt(np.dot(...))`.

Comment: `sqrt` from the Python `math` module is even faster on scalars. `scipy.linalg.norm` may be faster than `np.linalg.norm`; I've submitted a patch to NumPy that changes `linalg.norm` to use `dot`, but it hasn't been merged yet.

Comment: @larsman: Thanks for the info. I didn't know `math.sqrt` is (at the moment) so much faster than `np.sqrt` on scalars (about 18x on my machine).

Comment: I suppose `math.sqrt` will always be faster than `np.sqrt` when operating on scalars since `np.sqrt`'s overall performance would be slowed if it had to check its input for scalars.

Comment: This is very neat, would you be so kind to add the equivalent for 2D? I know that for rotating w.r.t OX axis we can just compute new coords as: `(x*np.cos(theta)-y*np.sin(theta), x*np.sin(theta)+y*np.cos(theta))`, but how should this be modified when the axis of rotation is not OX any longer? thanks for any tips.

Comment: nice solution,   it looks like the point of  rotation is [0,0,0],  what  do I need  to do,  if  I want  to change  to point of rotation?

Comment: @TomK: To rotate around an arbitrary point `P`, shift all points so that `P` is moved to the origin, rotate about the origin, then shift all points so that the origin is moved back to `P`. For example, to rotate point `M` about `P`, you would calculate `R(M-P) + P`, where `R` is the rotation matrix.

Comment: Shouldn't axis be x, y or z? What's that vector?

Comment: @Schütze 3d rotations can be around any vector, not just the three cartesian axes. So if you want to rotate about the x-axis, you'd just use axis=[1,0,0]—and similar for y and z.

Answer (score 57):

A one-liner, with numpy/scipy functions.

We use the following:

> let *a* be the unit vector along *axis*, i.e. *a = axis/norm(axis)*
>   and *A = I × a* be the skew-symmetric matrix associated to *a*, i.e. the cross product of the identity matrix with *a*
>
> then *M = exp(θ A)* is the rotation matrix.

```
from numpy import cross, eye, dot
from scipy.linalg import expm, norm

def M(axis, theta):
    return expm(cross(eye(3), axis/norm(axis)*theta))

v, axis, theta = [3,5,0], [4,4,1], 1.2
M0 = M(axis, theta)

print(dot(M0,v))
# [ 2.74911638  4.77180932  1.91629719]
```

`expm` [(code here)](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/linalg/matfuncs.py#L211) computes the taylor series of the exponential:
`\sum_{k=0}^{20} \frac{1}{k!} (θ A)^k`
, so it's time expensive, but readable and secure.
It can be a good way if you have few rotations to do but a lot of vectors.

Comment: What is the reference for the quote "let a be... then M = exp(θ A) is the rotation matrix." ?

Comment: Thanks. This Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation) is also useful. Last question: could you explain how `cross(eye(3), axis/norm(axis)*theta)` get you the "cross-product matrix"?

Answer (score 22):

I just wanted to mention that if speed is required, wrapping unutbu's code in scipy's weave.inline and passing an already existing matrix as a parameter yields a 20-fold decrease in the running time.

The code (in rotation_matrix_test.py):

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

from math import cos, sin, sqrt
import numpy.random as nr

from scipy import weave

def rotation_matrix_weave(axis, theta, mat = None):
    if mat == None:
        mat = np.eye(3,3)

    support = "#include <math.h>"
    code = """
        double x = sqrt(axis[0] * axis[0] + axis[1] * axis[1] + axis[2] * axis[2]);
        double a = cos(theta / 2.0);
        double b = -(axis[0] / x) * sin(theta / 2.0);
        double c = -(axis[1] / x) * sin(theta / 2.0);
        double d = -(axis[2] / x) * sin(theta / 2.0);

        mat[0] = a*a + b*b - c*c - d*d;
        mat[1] = 2 * (b*c - a*d);
        mat[2] = 2 * (b*d + a*c);

        mat[3*1 + 0] = 2*(b*c+a*d);
        mat[3*1 + 1] = a*a+c*c-b*b-d*d;
        mat[3*1 + 2] = 2*(c*d-a*b);

        mat[3*2 + 0] = 2*(b*d-a*c);
        mat[3*2 + 1] = 2*(c*d+a*b);
        mat[3*2 + 2] = a*a+d*d-b*b-c*c;
    """

    weave.inline(code, ['axis', 'theta', 'mat'], support_code = support, libraries = ['m'])

    return mat

def rotation_matrix_numpy(axis, theta):
    mat = np.eye(3,3)
    axis = axis/sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    a = cos(theta/2.)
    b, c, d = -axis*sin(theta/2.)

    return np.array([[a*a+b*b-c*c-d*d, 2*(b*c-a*d), 2*(b*d+a*c)],
                  [2*(b*c+a*d), a*a+c*c-b*b-d*d, 2*(c*d-a*b)],
                  [2*(b*d-a*c), 2*(c*d+a*b), a*a+d*d-b*b-c*c]])
```

The timing:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> 
>>> setup = """
... import numpy as np
... import numpy.random as nr
... 
... from rotation_matrix_test import rotation_matrix_weave
... from rotation_matrix_test import rotation_matrix_numpy
... 
... mat1 = np.eye(3,3)
... theta = nr.random()
... axis = nr.random(3)
... """
>>> 
>>> timeit.repeat("rotation_matrix_weave(axis, theta, mat1)", setup=setup, number=100000)
[0.36641597747802734, 0.34883809089660645, 0.3459300994873047]
>>> timeit.repeat("rotation_matrix_numpy(axis, theta)", setup=setup, number=100000)
[7.180983066558838, 7.172032117843628, 7.180462837219238]
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is an elegant method using quaternions that are blazingly fast; I can calculate 10 million rotations per second with appropriately vectorised numpy arrays. It relies on the quaternion extension to numpy found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-quaternion).

Quaternion Theory:
A quaternion is a number with one real and 3 imaginary dimensions usually written as `q = w + xi + yj + zk` where 'i', 'j', 'k' are imaginary dimensions. Just as a unit complex number 'c' can represent all 2d rotations by `c=exp(i * theta)`, a unit quaternion 'q' can represent all 3d rotations by `q=exp(p)`, where 'p' is a pure imaginary quaternion set by your axis and angle.

We start by converting your axis and angle to a quaternion whose imaginary dimensions are given by your axis of rotation, and whose magnitude is given by half the angle of rotation in radians. The 4 element vectors `(w, x, y, z)` are constructed as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import quaternion as quat

v = [3,5,0]
axis = [4,4,1]
theta = 1.2 #radian

vector = np.array([0.] + v)
rot_axis = np.array([0.] + axis)
axis_angle = (theta*0.5) * rot_axis/np.linalg.norm(rot_axis)
```

First, a numpy array of 4 elements is constructed with the real component w=0  for both the vector to be rotated `vector` and the rotation axis `rot_axis`. The axis angle representation is then constructed by normalizing then multiplying by half the desired angle `theta`. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385028/concise-description-of-why-rotation-quaternions-use-half-the-angle) for why half the angle is required.

Now create the quaternions `v` and `qlog` using the library, and get the unit rotation quaternion `q` by taking the exponential.

```
vec = quat.quaternion(*v)
qlog = quat.quaternion(*axis_angle)
q = np.exp(qlog)
```

Finally, the rotation of the vector is calculated by the following operation.

```
v_prime = q * vec * np.conjugate(q)

print(v_prime) # quaternion(0.0, 2.7491163, 4.7718093, 1.9162971)
```

Now just discard the real element and you have your rotated vector!

```
v_prime_vec = v_prime.imag # [2.74911638 4.77180932 1.91629719] as a numpy array
```

Note that this method is particularly efficient if you have to rotate a vector through many sequential rotations, as the quaternion product can just be calculated as q = q1 * q2 * q3 * q4 * ... * qn and then the vector is only rotated by 'q' at the very end using v' = q * v * conj(q).

This method gives you a seamless transformation between axis angle <---> 3d rotation operator simply by `exp` and `log` functions (yes `log(q)` just returns the axis-angle representation!). For further clarification of how quaternion multiplication etc. work, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870393/rotating-coordinate-system-via-a-quaternion)

Comment: Surprisingly, `np.conjugate(q)` seems to take longer than `np.exp(qlog)` despite it seems equivalent to just `quat.quaternion(q.real, *(-q.imag))`

Comment: I understand this is an old thread, but I have a question about the implementation of this method here if anyone is able to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64988678/applying-quaternion-rotation-to-a-vector-time-series

Answer (score 12):

Use scipy's [`Rotation.from_rotvec()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_rotvec.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_rotvec). The argument is the rotation vector (a unit vector) multiplied by the rotation angle in rads.

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
from numpy.linalg import norm


v = [3, 5, 0]
axis = [4, 4, 1]
theta = 1.2

axis = axis / norm(axis)  # normalize the rotation vector first
rot = Rotation.from_rotvec(theta * axis)

new_v = rot.apply(v)  
print(new_v)    # results in [2.74911638 4.77180932 1.91629719]
```

There are several more ways to use [`Rotation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation) based on what data you have about the rotation:

- [`from_quat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_quat.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_quat) Initialized from quaternions.
- [`from_dcm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_dcm.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_dcm) Initialized from direction cosine matrices.
- [`from_euler`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler) Initialized from Euler angles.

---

<sub>**Off-topic note:** One line code is *not* necessarily better code as implied by some users.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

I made a fairly complete library of 3D mathematics for Python{2,3}. It still does not use Cython, but relies heavily on the efficiency of numpy. You can find it here with pip:

```
python[3] -m pip install math3d
```

Or have a look at my gitweb http://git.automatics.dyndns.dk/?p=pymath3d.git  and now also on github: https://github.com/mortlind/pymath3d .

Once installed, in python you may create the orientation object which can rotate vectors, or be part of transform objects. E.g. the following code snippet composes an orientation that represents a rotation of 1 rad around the axis [1,2,3], applies it to the vector [4,5,6], and prints the result:

```
import math3d as m3d
r = m3d.Orientation.new_axis_angle([1,2,3], 1)
v = m3d.Vector(4,5,6)
print(r * v)
```

The output would be

```
<Vector: (2.53727, 6.15234, 5.71935)>
```

This is more efficient, by a factor of approximately four, as far as I can time it, than the oneliner using scipy posted by B. M. above. However, it requires installation of my math3d package.

Comment: I know this is very weird but I can't find a different way of contacting you. Would it be possible to use the math3d library to create 2D projections of 3D functions over an arbitrary axis more easily? For example, imagine projecting a normal distribution on the xy plane from the z axis. Now Imagine moving by the polar angle theta away from the z axis (as in spherical coord. notation) and projecting the normal dist on a plane that is also now rotated by theta in reference to xy? It's like orthogonal projection + integration. I can open a new question for this if you want.

Comment: Hi, ljetbo, I think this sounds difficult, or just not very easy with math3d. The function would imply, I guess, an analytical function, whereas math3d works better with point sets. Further, you seem to be talking about a scalar field over the plane (R(2)), whereas math3d deals with the Special Euclidean group (SE+(3)). It may be possible to do what you wish, but I have no immediate idea about how to mix in an analytical function with math3d.

Answer (score 3):

Using pyquaternion is extremely simple; to install it (while still in python), run in your console:

```
import pip;
pip.main(['install','pyquaternion'])
```

Once installed:

```
  from pyquaternion import Quaternion
  v = [3,5,0]
  axis = [4,4,1]
  theta = 1.2 #radian
  rotated_v = Quaternion(axis=axis,angle=theta).rotate(v)
```

Answer (score 3):

It can also be solved using quaternion theory:

```
def angle_axis_quat(theta, axis):
    """
    Given an angle and an axis, it returns a quaternion.
    """
    axis = np.array(axis) / np.linalg.norm(axis)
    return np.append([np.cos(theta/2)],np.sin(theta/2) * axis)

def mult_quat(q1, q2):
    """
    Quaternion multiplication.
    """
    q3 = np.copy(q1)
    q3[0] = q1[0]*q2[0] - q1[1]*q2[1] - q1[2]*q2[2] - q1[3]*q2[3]
    q3[1] = q1[0]*q2[1] + q1[1]*q2[0] + q1[2]*q2[3] - q1[3]*q2[2]
    q3[2] = q1[0]*q2[2] - q1[1]*q2[3] + q1[2]*q2[0] + q1[3]*q2[1]
    q3[3] = q1[0]*q2[3] + q1[1]*q2[2] - q1[2]*q2[1] + q1[3]*q2[0]
    return q3

def rotate_quat(quat, vect):
    """
    Rotate a vector with the rotation defined by a quaternion.
    """
    # Transfrom vect into an quaternion 
    vect = np.append([0],vect)
    # Normalize it
    norm_vect = np.linalg.norm(vect)
    vect = vect/norm_vect
    # Computes the conjugate of quat
    quat_ = np.append(quat[0],-quat[1:])
    # The result is given by: quat * vect * quat_
    res = mult_quat(quat, mult_quat(vect,quat_)) * norm_vect
    return res[1:]

v = [3, 5, 0]
axis = [4, 4, 1]
theta = 1.2 

print(rotate_quat(angle_axis_quat(theta, axis), v))
# [2.74911638 4.77180932 1.91629719]
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am the author of this package

While special classes for rotations can be convenient, in some cases one needs rotation matrices (e.g. for working with other libraries like the affine_transform functions in scipy). To avoid everyone implementing their own little matrix generating functions, there exists a tiny pure python package which does nothing more than providing convenient rotation matrix generating functions. The package is on github ([mgen](https://github.com/NOhs/mgen)) and can be installed via pip:

```
pip install mgen
```

Example usage copied from the readme:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

from mgen import rotation_around_axis
from mgen import rotation_from_angles
from mgen import rotation_around_x

matrix = rotation_from_angles([np.pi/2, 0, 0], 'XYX')
matrix.dot([0, 1, 0])
# array([0., 0., 1.])

matrix = rotation_around_axis([1, 0, 0], np.pi/2)
matrix.dot([0, 1, 0])
# array([0., 0., 1.])

matrix = rotation_around_x(np.pi/2)
matrix.dot([0, 1, 0])
# array([0., 0., 1.])
```

Note that the matrices are just regular numpy arrays, so no new data-structures are introduced when using this package.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to rotate a 3D model around one of the three axes {x, y, z} in which that model was embedded and this was the top result for a search of how to do this in numpy. I used the following simple function:

```
def rotate(X, theta, axis='x'):
  '''Rotate multidimensional array `X` `theta` degrees around axis `axis`'''
  c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
  if axis == 'x': return np.dot(X, np.array([
    [1.,  0,  0],
    [0 ,  c, -s],
    [0 ,  s,  c]
  ]))
  elif axis == 'y': return np.dot(X, np.array([
    [c,  0,  -s],
    [0,  1,   0],
    [s,  0,   c]
  ]))
  elif axis == 'z': return np.dot(X, np.array([
    [c, -s,  0 ],
    [s,  c,  0 ],
    [0,  0,  1.],
  ]))
```