# Finding the bisecting plane between two intersecting lines

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Given two vectors which intersect at a point in 3D space, I would like to determine (and display) the plane which bisects these lines.

So far I have done the following:

0) Plotted the vectors (red)

1) Computed the cross-product (blue) and the dot product angle between the two vectors.

2) Rotated one of the vector by the 1/2 the angle between them, using the cross-product vector as the axis of rotation. The result is normal to the plane (green).

3) Using the normal, solve for 'd' in the a*x+b*y+c*z+d = 0 equation of the plane.

4) Plot the resultant plane.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import numpy as np
    import math


    def unit_vector(vector):
        """ Returns the unit vector of the vector.  """
        return vector / np.linalg.norm(vector)

    def angle_between(v1, v2):
        v1_u = unit_vector(v1)
        v2_u = unit_vector(v2)
        return np.arccos(np.clip(np.dot(v1_u, v2_u), -1.0, 1.0))

    def rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
        axis = np.asarray(axis)
        axis = axis / math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
        a = math.cos(theta / 2.0)
        b, c, d = -axis * math.sin(theta / 2.0)
        aa, bb, cc, dd = a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d
        bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b * c, a * d, a * c, a * b, b * d, c * d
        return np.array([[aa + bb - cc - dd, 2 * (bc + ad), 2 * (bd - ac)],
                         [2 * (bc - ad), aa + cc - bb - dd, 2 * (cd + ab)],
                         [2 * (bd + ac), 2 * (cd - ab), aa + dd - bb - cc]])

    #Path of points to plot
    pathPoints = np.array ([[ 3,  0, 30], 
                            [13,  7, 25], 
                            [23, 12, 12]]) 

    #Initialize flight path array
    flightPath = []
    lineSegment = np.array ([0,0,0,0,0,0])

    for cntr, point in enumerate (pathPoints):
        #skip the last point in the sequence
        if pathPoints.shape[0] == cntr + 1: #shape is 1-based
            break

        print ('Point #%d' % cntr, point)

        nextPoint = pathPoints[cntr+1]
        print ('Next Point #%d' % cntr, nextPoint)

        lineSegment = np.zeros(6)
        lineSegment[:3] = point
        diff = np.subtract (nextPoint, point)
        print ('Diff #%d' % cntr, diff)
        lineSegment[3:] = diff
        print ('LineSeg #%d' % cntr, lineSegment)

        flightPath.append (lineSegment)

    print ('Flight Path array ', flightPath)

    #Create the plot
    plotSize = 15
    plt3d = plt.figure(figsize=(plotSize,plotSize)).gca(projection='3d')

    #set the plot limits
    axisMin=0
    axisMax=30
    plt3d.set_xlim([axisMin,axisMax])
    plt3d.set_ylim([axisMin,axisMax])
    plt3d.set_zlim([axisMin,axisMax])
    plt3d.set_xlabel('x')
    plt3d.set_ylabel('y')
    plt3d.set_zlabel('z')

    for vector in flightPath:
        v = np.array([vector[3],vector[4],vector[5]])
        vlength = np.linalg.norm(v)
        plt3d.quiver(vector[0],vector[1],vector[2],vector[3],vector[4],vector[5], 
                  pivot='tail', arrow_length_ratio=2.0/vlength,color='red')

    #Compute the cross product at the intersection points, and then a plane which
    #bisects the intersection point.
    flightPlanes = []
    flightPlaneOffsets = []

    for cntr, currVec in enumerate (flightPath):
        #skip the last point in the sequence
        if len (flightPath) == cntr + 1: #shape is 1-based
            break

        print ('Vector #%d' % cntr, currVec)

        #Compute the cross product normal 
        nextVec = flightPath[cntr+1]

        print ('Next Vector #%d' % cntr, nextVec)

        #Compute the cross product of the differences
        crossProd = np.cross (np.negative (currVec[3:]), nextVec[3:])

        vlength = np.linalg.norm(crossProd)

        print ('Cross Product #%d' % cntr, crossProd)

        #Scale the length of the cross product in order to display on the 
        #plot. Determining the plane doesn't depend on length.
        crossProd = np.multiply (crossProd, 15/vlength)
        print ('Scaled Cross Product #%d' % cntr, crossProd)

        #Recompute the scaled length
        vlength = np.linalg.norm(crossProd)

        plt3d.quiver(nextVec[0], nextVec[1], nextVec[2], 
                crossProd[0], crossProd[1], crossProd[2],
                pivot='tail', arrow_length_ratio=2.0/vlength,color='blue')

        #Generate the bisecting plane

        #Compute the angle between the vectors
        bisectAngle = angle_between (np.negative (currVec[3:]), nextVec[3:]) / 2
        print ('Bisect angle between #%d %.2f deg' % (cntr, np.degrees(bisectAngle)))

        #Determining normal vector
        #Compute the normal vector to the plane
        #See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802577/rotation-of-3d-vector
        normalVecA = np.dot(rotation_matrix(crossProd, 2*np.pi-bisectAngle), nextVec[:3])

        #Scale the length of the normal vector in order to display on the 
        #plot. Determining the plane doesn't depend on length.
        vlength = np.linalg.norm(normalVecA)

        plt3d.quiver(nextVec[0], nextVec[1], nextVec[2],
                normalVecA[0], normalVecA[1], normalVecA[2], 
                pivot='tail', arrow_length_ratio=2.0/vlength,color='green')

        print ('Normal vector A #%d' % cntr, normalVecA)

        #Create a view of one of the normal vectors
        normalVec = normalVecA

        #Plane point is the intersection point
        planePoint  = np.array(nextVec[:3])
        print ('Plane point #%d' % cntr, planePoint)
        # A plane is a*x+b*y+c*z+d=0
        # [a,b,c] is the normal. Thus, we have to calculate
        # d and we're set
        d = -planePoint.dot(normalVec)
        print ('D offset is #%d' % cntr, d)

        # create x,y
        gridSize = 3
        ptsSpacing = 10 / abs (normalVec[2])
        xRange = np.array(np.arange(nextVec[0]-gridSize, 
                                    nextVec[0]+gridSize+1, ptsSpacing))
        yRange = np.array(np.arange(nextVec[1]-gridSize, 
                                    nextVec[1]+gridSize+1, ptsSpacing))
        print ('Xrange #%d' % cntr, xRange)
        xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xRange, yRange)

        # calculate corresponding z
        z = (-normalVec[0] * xx - normalVec[1] * yy - d) * 1. /normalVec[2]

        flightPlanes.append(normalVec)
        flightPlaneOffsets.append(d)

        # plot the surface
        plt3d.plot_surface(xx, yy, z, alpha=0.3)

    plt.show()
```

[image: Plot showing two vectors and the incorrect bisector plane]

I expect the cross-product vector (blue), which is the axis of rotation, also should be on the bisecting plane (however this is not the case).
The following code line is key:

```
    normalVecA = np.dot(rotation_matrix(crossProd, 2*np.pi-bisectAngle), nextVec[:3])
```

I tried setting the angle to just 'bisectAngle' and '-bisectAngle' and it doesn't appear to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this special case, the normal vector for the new plane is just the concatenation of the two vectors. I would go like this:

1. given three points `p1,p2,p3` compute `a1 = unit(p2-p1)`, `a2=unit(p3-p2)`
2. compute the normal vector of the plane as `n = (a2+a1)`
3. construct the plane passing `p2` with normal `n`.

Comment: Thanks Quang that is a very nice solution (which does work!). Here is the Python code for this: `
    unitVectorA1 = unit_vector (currVec[3:])
    unitVectorA2 = unit_vector (nextVec[3:])
    normalVec = unitVectorA2 + unitVectorA1`