# Get xyz coordinates from starting point, quaternion and moved distance

Tags: c#, quaternions

In my case I have a starting coordinate x,y,z, an orientation in Quaternion and I know the moved distance.

Basically I would like to know the x',y',z' after applying the transformation and the forward movement. So I am trying to move a point in 3D using quaternion. I guess it should be just a simple calculation but for some reason I cannot find the solution that easily.

In previously I converted the Quaternion to Euler angles and used them to calculate the x',y',z'. Unfortunately because of the Gimbal lock this solution is not suitable for me anymore.

I have found a few example for example this one in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870393/rotating-coordinate-system-via-a-quaternion) and here's an other in [C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36868/Quaternion-Mathematics-and-D-Library-with-C-and-G), but I still did not get the formula of them as they are discussing the rotation instead of the movement it self, the C# example just changes the middle point of the cube and then it redraws it with the rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel ? This kind of operation is best handled via matrixes - and C# has even support for it.

```
// PresentationCore.dll 
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

Matrix3D matrix = Matrix3D.Identity;
matrix.Translate(new Vector3D(x, y, z));
matrix.Rotate(quaterion);
var newPoint = matrix.Transform(point);
```

Comment: Let me know if I am wrong but I think here you assume that I know the movement vector, which I do not. My question is basically the movement vector as I know the direction of the movement from quternion and the distance.

Comment: Matrix operations are cumulative - so you first "rotate" the matrix and then you "walk" towards one direction - so you know the vector, it is (Distance, 0, 0).

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot:P I was just playing with my quaternion data as it is not in the same format/order than the Media3D one.