# Python: How do I 'zero' or 'tare' 3D rotation coordinates?

Tags: python, matrix, quaternions, angle

(Python) I am using an IMU (Inertial Measurement Unit) attachated to a raspberry pi that provides angles of [roll, pitch, yaw].

The chip seems to have a hardware 'zero' and cannot calibrate it, therefore in software I want to.

i.e. **When I turn on the chip I may get a reading of `theta = [10, 5, -80]`* and want to set that to my 'zero'.**
*the angles are in the range +- 180deg and can be in rad if easier

I have a crude workaround but am after something more elegant:

```
tare = [*read initial angles*] # This only gets set once
    #inside a loop
    theta = [*read the imu*]
    deg = map(operator.sub, theta, tare) #zero correction, deg = actual (theta) - 'zero' (tare)
    for d in deg: # if angle > 180 then put angle in terms of +_ 180
    if d > 180: d = d - 360
    elif d  < -179: d = d + 360
    print deg
```

Ive been looking into this for a while now and some people have mentioned **quaternions** and rotation **matrices** but I cant get my head around it.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is a link to someone achieveing it in c++ for the same Lib I am using to get the data from the IMU:
[Link](https://richardstechnotes.wordpress.com/2014/11/20/using-quaternions-to-correct-imu-installation-offsets/)

Other potentially useful (stackoverflow) link:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870393/rotating-coordinate-system-via-a-quaternion)

Answer (score 0):

You could do exactly what you're doing a little more concisely like this:

```
def correction(args):
    d = args[0] - args[1]
    return d-360 if d > 180 else d+360 if d < -179 else d

tare = [10, 5, -80]

#inside the loop
theta = [10, 5, -80]
print map(correction, zip(tare, theta))  # --> [0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

1-way, Map your tare angles from euler to a rotation matrix.  (or to a quat if you like)   then invert your rotation matrix (which will be its transpose) - as rotMatA. take your incoming euler, map that to a rot mat (as rotMatB), and multiply your tare rot map times it.   From there  you can covert back to euler if you like like

```
rotMatA =eulerToRotMat(tareAngles).transpose()

rotMatB = eulerToRotMat( incomingAngles)

netResult= rotMatToEuler( rotMatA * rotMatB)
```

get the rotMat to Euler conversions from a library (better), or implement your own using a source like:  http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToMatrix/